# How use flask route with class based view?

Tags: python, flask, routes, django-class-based-views

Django style Class Based Views cool and powerful feature. But Flask style routers more suitable to the free style of app structure.
How can I do something like this:

```
@app.route("/")
class MyView(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello word"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find such feature in the official flask documentation. And also I did not find any solution on the internet or a similar question at Stack Overflow, so I prepared a snippet for this case.

```
import types

from flask import Blueprint
from flask.views import MethodView


# decorator code
def class_route(self, rule, endpoint, **options):
    """
    This decorator allow add routed to class view.
    :param self: any flask object that have `add_url_rule` method.
    :param rule: flask url rule.
    :param endpoint: endpoint name
    """

    def decorator(cls):
        self.add_url_rule(rule, view_func=cls.as_view(endpoint), **options)
        return cls

    return decorator

    # Usage
    # I use `Blueprint` and `MethodView`, but it should work correct with `App` and `View` to.


bp = Blueprint("bp", __name__, template_folder="templates")


@class_route(bp, "/", "my_view")
class MyView(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello world"


# Advanced usage
# Add decorator as class method
bp.class_route = types.MethodType(class_route, bp)


# And use is as bultin decorator
@bp.class_route("/advanced", "advanced_my_view")
class AdvancedMyView(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello world!"
```

Comment: This is unnecessary and a better-quality search on your part would've shown you the [`Flask-Classful`](http://flask-classful.teracy.org/) extension.

Answer (score 9):

from flask documentation(https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/):

```py
from flask.views import View

class ShowUsers(View):
    def dispatch_request(self):
        users = User.query.all()
        return render_template('users.html', objects=users)

app.add_url_rule('/users/', view_func=ShowUsers.as_view('show_users'))
```

the last string converts to the function and does registration(`@app.route(...)`) to the app

Answer (score -1):

I fancy D.I. and prefer the approach described below:

```
class MyBlueprint:
    def __init__(self, ...some resources...):
        self.resources = ...
        self.blueprint = Blueprint('youdomus_blueprint', __name__)

        self.blueprint.add_url_rule('/my-route', view_func=self.my_method)

    def my_method(self):
        ...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(MyBlueprint(...).blueprint)
```

Below a running example. A sample module `bp_example.py` contains some application logic class:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request

class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, greetings: str, default_name: str):
        self.blueprint = Blueprint('flask_example', __name__)
        self.blueprint.add_url_rule('/a-method', view_func=self.a_method)
        self.greetings = greetings
        self.default_name = default_name

    def a_method(self):
        return jsonify(f'{self.greetings}, {request.args.get("name") or self.default_name}')
```

The main module use it like this:

```
def main():
    import sys
    from bp_example import Greeter

    greeter = Greeter(
        greetings=sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'Hello',
        default_name=sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 'World',
    )

    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(greeter.blueprint)

    app.run(port=5000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What's important here is that Blueprint routes definitions need an instance, not a class, otherwise you end with some globals around and unit testing becomes a mess.

Comment: How this works? can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: I don't think this works. There are no routes defined

Comment: If you look at Flask route annotation code, you'll find it just invokes add_url_rule. See flask/blueprints.py, class Blueprint, method route. I don't like flask style using annotations at all because it mixes configuration, which is dynamic, with code definition which is static. The code I posted works, I usually test it before postsing.